# Applying CSS using Child/ Parent technique

Tags: css

Someone wrote this CSS code for me which applies it to a webpage on my site.. it works fine. However, I want to apply it on a different page as shown below. I need the `ltlitems` displayed with this CSS applied.. I'm guessing it applies it to the `div` around it? Apologies, I'm just learning. I am unsure how this part works..  `h1:first-child + p + div > div:first-child`

```
<div class="pageContent">

    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>

    <iframe width="90%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v10" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h2>How To Sell</h2>
    <p>Selling couldn't be easier..</p>
    <asp:Image ID="HowToSell" alt="How To Sell" runat="server" class="screenfit" ImageUrl="~/files/images/howTo.png" />
    <h2>Featured Boxes</h2>

    <p>Below are some of our featured items</p>

    <div style="margin:auto; text-align:center;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltlItems" runat="server"> </asp:Literal>
    </div>
</div>


.pageContent > h1:first-child + p + div > div:first-child {
   display: -webkit-box; 
   display: -webkit-flex; 
   display: -moz-box; 
   display: -ms-flexbox; 
   display: flex; 
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; 
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   -webkit-box-pack: center; 
   -webkit-justify-content: center; 
   -moz-box-pack: center; 
   -ms-flex-pack: center; 
   justify-content: center; 
}
```

Comment: visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: replace your code with this `.pageContent div {}`

Comment: You didn't specify which div should be affected by the CSS

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Does that apply to all pages with a div though as it's only this one I want it to apply this to. Thanks again.

Comment: It applies only to pages where that css statement is found. You would need to add it to any/all pages you want that css applied to. If you happen to add the same css statement twice to the same page, the second statement will override the first statement. If both are the same, it is untidy but harms nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h1:first-child + p + div > div:first-child
```

Find the first `<h1>` tag . . .

With a `<p>` tag immediately below that

And a `<div>` immediately following that

And inside that div, there should be one or more divs

But select only the first div and apply the styling here

---

`first-child` means: just the first one that applies

`+` means: the next element on the same level (not inside/under)

`>` means: inside/under

---

Looking at the CSS code on the question, though, there is an obvious problem if that is how it is written on your site.

CSS, when included on the page like that, should be between `<style>` tags, thus:

```
<style>
.pageContent > h1:first-child + p + div > div:first-child {
   display: -webkit-box; 
   display: -webkit-flex; 
   display: -moz-box; 
   display: -ms-flexbox; 
   display: flex; 
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; 
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   -webkit-box-pack: center; 
   -webkit-justify-content: center; 
   -moz-box-pack: center; 
   -ms-flex-pack: center; 
   justify-content: center; 
}
</style>
```

Also, the `-webkit`, `-ms`, `-moz` prefixes are probably no longer required. They were needed only for a couple of years while the different browsers were being updated to include new features. So, for example, this:

```
   -webkit-box-pack: center; 
   -webkit-justify-content: center; 
   -moz-box-pack: center; 
   -ms-flex-pack: center; 
   justify-content: center;
```

can probably be replaced with just this:

```
   justify-content: center;
```

Indeed, the whole thing can probably be reduced to:

```
<style>
.pageContent > h1:first-child + p + div > div:first-child {
   display: flex; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   justify-content: center; 
}
</style>
```